# Rails routing confusion due to :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using devise for authentication.  When signing up users create a profile name that I would like to use as their profile route.  So, it might look like this: www.myapp.com/profile-name.  The problem I'm running into is with the routes not going to the right place.

*routes.rb*

```
resources :majors do 
  resources :reviews
end 

devise_for :users

...

match '/:id' => 'users#show', as: :user_profile
```

I've placed the :user_profile route at the bottom of my routes file.  Part of my rake routes looks like this:

```
major GET            /majors/:id(.:format)   majors#show
user_profile GET     /:id(.:format)          users#show
```

On the profile page (myapp.com/my-custom-profile-name) there are no problems.  But on the majors show page I use the `user_profile_path` to link to a user's profile and the url is www.myapp.com/:id - with the :id being the major :id.  So, the :id of the major is getting mixed in with the user_profile :id.

My users controller looks like this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
  @reviews = @user.reviews
end
```

I have changed the url around, tested it on different areas, changed the order of my routes file, searched and tested this all day long.  I cannot figure out what I'm missing.  I think it's really simple but it's eluding me.  Any ideas?

---

**SOLUTION:**

The solution was first get the routes correct.  Since I've created a custom, dynamic url (myapp.com/user-profile-name) I needed to call the id in the route:

```
get '/:id' => 'users#show', as: :id
```

That changed my routes to look like this:

```
id GET        /:id(.:format)              users#show
```

Users share reviews and their name is posted next to their review.  I was having trouble linking to their profile from their name on their review.  I was able to do that on the view like this:

```
<%= link_to review.user.profile_name, id_path(review.user.profile_name) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to a specific user profile, you need to pass the user profile ID into the user_profile named route:

`user_profile_path(@user)`

Comment: That results in the following routing error:

No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"show", :id=>nil}

Comment: How do you user the path helper on the view?

Comment: that was just an example, I'm guessing @user is returning nil.  You need to pass the user into the helper in whatever way you want.  I don't know what your 'major' controller looks like, but you need to set a user var there and then pass that into the helper like my example.

Comment: Thanks for your help messick - you got me going in the right direction.